# Unable to require a js file from a gem in asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a local gem. And there is a js file:

```
  app/assets/javascripts/autocomplete_location/location_autocomplete.js
```

Now I am trying to use this gem in my rails project. I am able to use it's other ruby files, but can't include the above js file. I have tried putting engine.rb file in my gem. Still no luck.

I tried

```
  //= require autocomplete_locations/location_autocomplete
```

in application.js file of my project. Still, when I start server and open any page, it throws this error:

```
 Sprockets::FileNotFound > couldn't find file 'autocomplete_locations/location_autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Comment: try:  <//= require autocomplete_locations/location_autocomplete> instead of //= require autocomplete_locations/locationAutocomplete

Comment: Can you try //= require autocomplete_location

Comment: @prasanthrubyist tried, can't find file error

Comment: @LuisMenjivar did you try this? it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your file name and also make sure your file in vender folder

Comment: @Mukarram I did not try it. But I saw that you named the file `location_autocomplete.js` and the error is telling you that it cannot find a file named `locationAutocomplete`

Comment: @LuisMenjivar Sorry, it was my mistake. Update the question. It's not the reason though.

Answer (score 1):

`//= require autocomplete_locations/location_autocomplete` is still not the same as `'autocomplete_locations/location_autocomplete`. The folder being required is `autocomplete_locations` and the name of the folder containing the file is `autocomplete_location`. I didn't catch that neither on my previous comment. If that does not solve the issue. Try requiring and testing a different javascript file just to make sure it is not a problem with the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions, after struggling through several hit and trial, I solved this by adding below code in lib/autocomplete_locations.rb:

```
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    environment = Sprockets::Environment.new
    environment.append_path '../vendor/assets/javascripts'
  end
```

Now I am able to require my assets in rails project.